# How to force a download in PHP using a cookie? (file_get_contents or cURL)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, force-download

How can I force a download in PHP using cookies? I tried using file_get_contents and cURL, but I don't know if in file_get_contents it can use a cookie. 
I use this code, but it doesn't have a cookie:

```
<?php
$extensiones = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
$f = $_POST["direccion"];
$nombre_archivo = $_POST["nombre_archivo"];
if(strpos($f,"/") < 6){
    die("No puedes navegar por otros directorios");
}
$ftmp = explode(".",$f);
$fExt = strtolower($ftmp[count($ftmp)-1]);

if(!in_array($fExt,$extensiones)){
    die("<b>¡ERROR!</b> No es posible descargar archivos con la extensión $fExt");
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$nombre_archivo\"\n");
$fp=fopen("$f", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

And this other with cURL and a cookie, but the file is saved in the server and I don't want to that. I want to force the download for this user like the other code (file_get_contents), but using a cookie :(

```
<?php
// Data for the login
$raw_post = "&". http_build_query(array("user" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
$raw_post .= "&". http_build_query(array("password" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));

// Login
$ch = curl_init('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $raw_post );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);

// Download the file
$fp = fopen("hi.jpg", 'w+');
$ch = curl_init("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10773ae6687b55736e171c038b4228d2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Why the cookie? What purpose does the cookie serve?

Comment: The cookie is to have access a image or video of a account "locked"... like a profile no public (private).